# Error: Unable to resolve module `@react-native-community/toolbar-android`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-toolbar, react-native-vector-icons

Weirdly, the `react-native-vector-icons` was working well but by using `^` ("^6.6.0") for its version in the `package.json` file on the new release this error happens.

[image]

It's weird because two days ago it works well but now starting of my project ran to this error:

> error: Error: Unable to resolve module `@react-native-community/toolbar-android` from `node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\lib\toolbar-android.js`: @react-native-community/toolbar-android could not be found within the project.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

<del>After reading [this issue](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1193) and trying many solutions I reach to two solutions:</del>

- <del>You can delete all `node_modules` folder and put the version of `react-native-vector-icons` to `"6.6.0"` instead of `"^6.6.0"` and then install all packages again. absolutely, it is better to delete all caches and builds and start everything again. (***NOT Recommended***)</del>
- <del>You can install the `@react-native-community/toolbar-android` by using the below command:</del>

  ```bash
  yarn add @react-native-community/toolbar-android
  ```

  <del>Or</del>

  ```bash
  npm install --save @react-native-community/toolbar-android
  ```

<del>**Note**: Both of these solutions are temporary, and soonly this bug will be fixed, and there is no need to install the `toolbar-android` package.</del>

---

#### <del>Prev Update</del>

<del>I update the package to version `"^7.0.0"` on my project and still, the issue remains, so this solution is currently perseverance.</del>

---

#### New Update

This issue is fixed on version `"^7.1.0"` and there is no need to install the `@react-native-community/toolbar-android`.

But if you still need to have `@react-native-community/toolbar-android`, install the `0.2.1` version.

Comment: how i can update to `"^7.1.0"` ? i am still getting this issue.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil, for `npm` use npm commands for `yarn` use yarn commands, there is another way, completely remove it  and then install it again with the new version, if still getting this issue, you should know, there is another package that use `vector-icon` in itself and install the lower version, for fixing this issue still you should install `@react-native-community/toolbar-android`.

Answer (score 9):

Update the library

> react-native-vector-icons

to the latest version.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem too.
In my case, only works when I removed and added the package again with the latest version (7.0.0).

```
yarn remove react-native-vector-icons
yarn add react-native-vector-icons
```

Answer (score 5):

I had precisely the same error. All I had to do was install `toolbar-android` and done.

`npm install --save @react-native-community/toolbar-android`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that this question had already been answered by somebody else who elaborated more about how to fix this problem.

Comment: @MyKoryto The accepted answer crossed out the `npm install` section. I didn't want to upgrade to the new version of RN Vector Icons. Since installing the `toolbar-android` solved my case, thought I might post it here in case someone is in my situation. Cheers!

Comment: Alright! Makes sense, sorry for bothering you mate!

Comment: No problemo! Thanks!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Go the path `\node_modules\native-base\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\lib\toolbar-android.js`

Replace `import ToolbarAndroid from '@react-native-community/toolbar-android'` to `import {ToolbarAndroid} from './react-native';`

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error after upgrading from version 6 to 7. The issue can be fixed simply by resetting the cache.

Please try `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 0):

do this:
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -rf package.lock.json
npm i
react-native start --reset-cache

from your project directory

Answer (score 0):

Just Import it direct from react native it solves my problem

*node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\lib\toolbar-android.js*

```
import { ToolbarAndroid } from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, I solved it:
My environment:
RN: 0.61.5
Node: v12.18.3
OS: Windows 10 Pro

You can install react-native-vector-icons latest version (current 7.0.0).
And **do not** run auto-link (react-native link react-native-vector-icons)
Finally, running `react-native start --reset-cache`
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First let's understand the standard convention used in `package.json` for packege's version.
So if you see `~1.0.2` it means to install version `1.0.2` or the latest patch version such as `1.0.4`. If you see `^1.0.2` it means to install version `1.0.2` or the latest minor or patch version such as `1.1.0`.

Now, coming to the issue.

The issue is caused because you are having a version of `react-native-vector-icons` which is giving you some trouble.
Check it's version by this command under your project directory:

`npm list react-native-vector-icons --version`   \ is it `6.6.0` ??

No ?? . There is the problem. You need strictly `6.6.0` but you got something else.

**Solution:**

Delete `node_modules` directory under your project. Change the version of `react-native-vector-icons` in `package.json` to `6.6.0` (basically remove `^` to tell `npm` to get me exactly what I want. Nothing more, nothing less !)

Then do `npm install` !

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative is to use expo's vector Icons. Something like this.
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons".
Then render your Icon like this;

```
<Ionicons
  name="ios-exit-outline"
  color={colors.danger}
  size={28}
  style={{ marginRight: -15 }}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit this file node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\lib\toolbar-android.js

remove 'import ToolbarAndroid from '@react-native-community/toolbar-android';'
edit return null

Comment: terrible idea. since node_modules doesn't get into git, you will always go back to making the above change should you reinstall modules again, I believe.

Answer (score -4):

for this case you have not toolbar-android in your modules file and as friends saying you can fix it by  this command

**windows users:**

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/toolbar-android
```

**Mac users:**

```
yarn add @react-native-community/toolbar-android
```

**But IN GENERAL:** I wanna tell you an experience for you guys whenever you encounter with this kind of errors that start with **"Unable to resolve module"** .

if you have a look to the error we have a problem with the module that system is telling us.

if you have not that module . you can install it with the commands

**Windows users:**

npm install --save THE MODULE(attention: THE MODULE IS THE NAME OF PACKAGES OR MODULES that u need to install)

**and Mac users:**

```
yarn add THE MODULE(attention: THE MODULE IS THE NAME OF PACKAGES OR MODULES that u need to install)
```

for example lets look at this error:

```
error Unable to resolve module `@react-native-community/slider` from `App.js`: @react-native-community/slider could not be found within the project.
```

as you can see error is telling us this module could not be found within our project.
so we need install it with this command:
for windows programmers:

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/slider
```

and for mac programmers:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/slider
```

that's all.

I hope you understand me clearly and do not have problem with unable to resolve module errors and my command be useful for you.